# Mean square displacement in Python

Tags: python, loops, mean, square

I need to compute the mean square displacement for a (n, N) np array, where n is the lenght of the array and N represent the number of repetition (I am computing N different trajectories over the time).
So, the MSD is defined as:

MSD=<[x(t+tau)-x(t)]^2+[y(t+tau)-y(t)]^2>. The following is the code i computed but I think is not correct, since the output it gives me is a little bit weird (not completely but I expect something quite different).

```
MSD = np.zeros_like(x)
for delta in range(len(x)-1):
 for i in range(delta,len(x)-1):
   MSD[delta,:] += (x[i,:] - x[i-delta,:])**2+(y[i,:] - y[i-delta,:])**2
 MSD[delta,:] = MSD[delta,:] / (len(x) - delta)
```

Also I tried to change my code in this:

```
MSD=np.zeros_like(x)
for tau in range(n-1):
for i in range(tau,n-1):
    MSD[tau,:] += (x[i+tau,:] - x[i,:])**2+(y[i+tau,:] - y[i,:])**2
MSD[tau,:] = MSD[tau,:] / (n - tau)
```

but eventually I got this error here:

> index 1875 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1875.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264591/mean-square-displacement-python

Comment: not much, unfortunately I have to vector x=(n, N), y=(n, N) and I feel that the definition of their msd is mathematically unequal to mine...