# Mean square displacement for n-dim matrix python

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am ganna to use Mean square displacement (MSD) for 3-dim matrix. This solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/31266574/4025749 calculates MSD for (x,y) but I have a matrix with (x,y,z). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_displacement#Derivation_for_n-dimensions) says:

> Derivation for n-dimensions:
>
> MSD=2nDt.

and this code is used for `n = 2`:

```py
    import numpy as np
    r = np.sqrt(xdata**2 + ydata**2)
    diff = np.diff(r) #this calculates r(t + dt) - r(t)
    diff_sq = diff**2
    MSD = np.mean(diff_sq)
```

So, If I want to exploit this code for `n = 3`, Can I change it to below:

```py
    import numpy as np
    r = np.sqrt(xdata**2 + ydata**2 + zdata**2)
    diff = np.diff(r) #this calculates r(t + dt) - r(t)
    diff_sq = diff**3
    MSD = np.mean(diff_sq)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you still want to write `diff_sq = diff**2`, as indicated in "diff squared".

Going from `n=2` to `n=3` only changes the way one computes distances, as you have done by adding the `zdata` vector into your square root.

Comment: However, you might need to use the `np.diff` function on the coordinates before computing distances, depending on what you are trying to achieve.